# Find answers/questions from the same anonymous user name

Tags: support, search, display-names, anonymous

How can I find other answers/questions/comments from a single anonymous user (they would have to use the same alias each time of course).

For instance, if there was an anonymous answer from "Steve", how can I find all other anonymous questions/answers from anonymous "Steve"?

I fully realize that one "Steve" might not be another "Steve".

Comment: Search their name in "Users" and check their recent activity?

Comment: @Gnoupi: I don't believe anonymous users show up in the Users list, nor do they have profile pages.

Comment: This could be a good API to provide -- moderators could use it to check if two users might be the same person.

Comment: unregistered users have profile pages and user links and such; is there a difference between unregistereds and anonymouses? (anonymice?)

Comment: @quack: Confused Jon is confused.

Comment: To further confuse matters, there are users who have unregistered accounts (posts associated with an ID, bio page, but no presence in user list) and users who've been deleted or are attached to posts migrated to a site where they've never had an account (no visible post association, no bio page).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the user id, just go to their profile page and check the url and then call the api.

i.e. for jeff's questions on SO

http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/users/1/questions?pagesize=100

for more info on the api see http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/help